# Inner join sql statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, Invoices and members, connected by PK/FK relationship through the field InvoiceNum. I have created the following sql and it works fine, and pulls 44 records as expected.

```
SELECT
  INVOICES.InvoiceNum,
  INVOICES.GroupNum,
  INVOICES.DivisionNum,
  INVOICES.DateBillFrom,
  INVOICES.DateBillTo
FROM INVOICES 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS ON INVOICES.InvoiceNum = MEMBERS.InvoiceNum
WHERE MEMBERS.MemberNum = '20032526000'
```

Now, I want to replace `INVOICES.GroupNum` and `INVOICES.DivisionNum` in the above query with `GroupName` and `DivisionName`. These values are present in the Groups and Divisions tables which also have the corresponding Group_num and Division_num fields. I have created the following sql. The problem is that it now pulls 528 records instead of 44!

```
SELECT
  INVOICES.InvoiceNum,
  INVOICES.DateBillFrom,
  INVOICES.DateBillTo,
  DIVISIONS.DIVISION_NAME,
  GROUPS.GROUP_NAME
FROM INVOICES 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS ON INVOICES.InvoiceNum = MEMBERS.InvoiceNum 
INNER JOIN GROUPS ON INVOICES.GroupNum = GROUPS.Group_Num
INNER JOIN DIVISIONS ON INVOICES.DivisionNum = DIVISIONS.Division_Num
WHERE MEMBERS.MemberNum = '20032526000'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there multiple Group Names per Group Number? Same for Divisions?

Comment: Looks like you have a many-to-one relationship between members/invoices and groups/divisions. You need to look at and decide whether you want to return invoices or groups or divisions

Comment: I'd recommend when asking questions to put your code in SQL Fiddle, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/, and share that link. It would make it simpler for people to see the potential relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one relation between your tables which is missing in your query. It gives you extra records. Find all common fields. Say, are divisions related to groups?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is fine, as far as the SQL syntax goes.

But the question you have to ask yourself (and answer it):

- How many rows in `Groups` do you get for that given `GroupNum`?
- Ditto for `Divisions` - how many rows exist for that `DivisionNum`?

It would appear that those numbers aren't unique - multiple rows exist for each number - therefore you get multiple rows returned